# How I can specify ms-planner storage place on SharePoint?

Tags: sharepoint, office365, microsoft-planner

I'm using Microsoft SharePoint and MS Planner, I have a plan that's connected to SharePoint website, so everything I post in planner automatically shows in SharePoint.

So whenever I upload an attachment it is uploaded to Sharepoint site/shared document

I want to create a specific folder inside documents and make attachments that I upload in planner go directly there.

is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Currently this is not supported. You can vote for the suggestion to add this feature though:

https://feedbackportal.microsoft.com/feedback/idea/91702db7-3252-ec11-a819-000d3a7c684e